# Is it possible to split VirtualBox Hard Drive to multiple volumes?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-player

VirtualBox hard drive usually has one  or a few files when you create a drive. I think it is good because you manage only a few files. However, I have out of space of my drive. Is it possible to span over other volume like in VM player?

Comment: Useful for transferring files between windows and linux using a standard (FAT32) USB stick

Answer (score 20):

Yes it is possible, though you need to use the VMDK disk format.

```
VBoxManage clonehd disk.vdi disk.vmdk --format VMDK --variant Split2G
```

This will create `disk.vmdk` (text file) along with a number of `disk-sXXX.vmdk` (data files). You should point your virtual machine to use the `disk.vmdk` file.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, what if you used the command:

```
vboxmanage clonehd hd1.vdi hd2.vmdk --format VMDK --variant Split2G --type normal --remember
```

Comment: Nice one. But the options "--type normal --remember" aren't recognized.

Comment: According to https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=77767 , this works but you need to relink the newly created disk because it changed UUID. Not tested yet

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox supports `.vmdk` files since 2.1. So you can convert your `.vdi` to 2GB-parts `.vmdk` and open it in VirtualBox. I don't know however how about spanning the files into different disks.